# 'while' loop not behaving as expected

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, scope, menu

**Background:**

I have made a program that takes a text input, applies encryption (a simple cipher) and saves the output to a list - if desired. Messages can also be decrypted.

The program is navigated through an options menu: 
1. Encrypt a message
2. View encrypted messages
3. Decrypt a message

To allow all sections of the program to access the same list (variable) of saved messages, I have written it within a class. Within the class exist def's that call on this list.

Only the 'encrypt a message' bit has been written so far.

**Problem:**

The user decision flow is made with two Y/N choices. 
However, the choices do not work - even if the user types in 'N' - my program thinks they have typed 'Y' in both cases.

```
def encrypt():
    def save_cip():#This function allows the user to save the ciphered message to the ciphered_messages if they choose
        choosing = True
        while choosing:
            save_choice = input("Would you like to save your Ciphered message? (Y/N)\n")
            if save_choice == "Y" or "y":
                print("You chose yes")
                cct.ciphered_messages.append(' '.join(["Message", str(len(cct.ciphered_messages)), ":", cipher]))
                choosing = False
            elif save_choice == "N" or "n":
                print("You chose no")
                choosing = False
                continue
            else:
                print("That was not a valid entry, please enter Y or N only")
                continue
```

I think the problem lay within the scope, and that somehow the same variable is not being referenced when setting and reading Y or N. I have been going up and down the same code for about 3 hours and still nothing, declaring all variables in many different places with no luck, so any advice greatly appreciated.

Full executable code:

```
class cct:

print("Welcome to the CaeserCipher tool v1.0")
menu_state = "main" #This is used to record what state the program is in
unciphered_messages = [] #Decrypted messages are saved here
ciphered_messages = [] #Encrypted messages are saved here

def menu(): #This is the main menu interface
    while cct.menu_state == "main": #This while 
        cct.menu_state = input("What would you like to do? \n 1: Encrypt a Message \n 2: View Encrypted Messages \n 3: Decrypt a message\n")
        if cct.menu_state == "1":
            cct.encrypt()
        elif cct.menu_state == "2":
            cct.view()
        elif cct.menu_state == "3":
            cct.decrypt()
        elif cct.menu_state == "main":
            print("\n\nWelcome back to the menu!\n\n")
        else:
            print("You did not enter a valid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 3.\n")
            cct.menu_state = "make_choice"
        continue

def encrypt():
    def save_cip():#This function allows the user to save the ciphered message to the ciphered_messages if they choose
        choosing = True
        while choosing:
            save_choice = input("Would you like to save your Ciphered message? (Y/N)\n")
            if save_choice == "Y" or "y":
                print("You chose yes")
                cct.ciphered_messages.append(' '.join(["Message", str(len(cct.ciphered_messages)), ":", cipher]))
                choosing = False
            elif save_choice == "N" or "n":
                print("You chose no")
                choosing = False
                continue
            else:
                print("That was not a valid entry, please enter Y or N only")
                continue

    #This while loop continually takes messages, gives the option of saving, and asks if you want to cipher another
    while cct.menu_state == "1":   
        text = input("Enter your message: ") #Enter the message you wish to cipher
        cipher = '' #Create a string for the cipher
        for char in text: #This for sub-loop will increment each character by 1. e.g. A -> B, T -> U, Z -> A
            if not char.isalpha():
                continue
            char = char.upper()
            code = ord(char) + 1
            if code > ord('Z'):
                code = ord('A')
            cipher += chr(code)
        print(' '.join(["Your ciphered message is:", cipher]))
        save_cip()
        print(cct.ciphered_messages)
        #This sub-while loop is reponsible for checking if you want to cipher another message
        #and making sure the user has made a valid choice
        choosing_another = True
        while choosing_another == True:
            choice_variable = input(' '.join(["You have", str(len(cct.ciphered_messages)), "saved messages \n", "Would you like to Cipher another? (Y/N)\n"]))
            if choice_variable == "Y" or "y":
                print("You chose yes")
                choosing_another = False
            elif choice_variable == "N" or "n":
                print("You chose no")
                cct.menu_state = "main"
                choosing_another = False
            else:
                choice_variable = input("That was not a valid entry, please enter Y or N only: \n")
                continue
    return


def view():
#TO BE CODED
    return

def decrypt():
    #TO BE CODED
    return
```

cct.menu()

Comment: I think the 'or "y" ' part treats the string y as a boolean value which is then true. Replace with ' or choosing=="y" '

Comment: If that is a problem within the while, isolate the that while loop, take out the encryption, and see if the error stills persists, afterwards reedit your questions with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is always true:

```
if save_choice == "Y" or "y":
```

bacause its interpreted as :

```
if (condition) or (condition):
```

the 1st condition is (save_choice == "Y")

the 2nd condition is just ( "y" ) which python interprets as 'True'

So the whole condition is always True.

U probably mean:

```
if save_choice == "Y" or save_choice == "y":
```

Or better :

```
if save_choice.lower() == "y":
```

Comment: This does work, thanks. It is not my while loop at all..! Can you clarify what is meant by the interpreting non empty string as true? What boolean statement is python interpreting?

Answer (score 0):

Not a python programmer, but i don't think python allows a "implied" subject for the **or** operator
--> IF save_choice == "Y" OR save_choice == "y" :